# Facebook Messenger does not give response in Rasa Core bot

Tags: facebook-messenger, rasa-core, facebook-webhooks, no-response

Steps followed to create Facebook Messenger Bot :

1)  Created a new app by clicking on Add New App.

2)  Moving to Product list and start configuring messenger (product), then moving to settings -> Basic and saved App secret for reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd5Kg.png

3)  Moving to Messenger settings (left panel), created a page with the same name as our app i.e “C2bot”,  on selecting the page (C2bot) “Page Access Token” will get generated . Saved the Token for reference

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7llC.png

4)  Then in same page configured Web hook callback URL (generated with Ngrok) , kept verify Token same as our app name C2bot . Then we checked all events for Web hook URL and subscribed our page. Now it shows the Web Hook configuration is completed with green check.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx5x4.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp3MA.png

5) Now we start pinging our chatbot and expecting auto response as per trained model

6)  We understand that we can track the request that are being sent to temporary URL generated by Ngrok and logs are below :

All Requests
POST /webhooks/facebook/webhook
200 OK  20.7ms
POST /webhooks/facebook/webhook
200 OK  28.46ms
POST /webhooks/facebook/webhook
200 OK  24.35ms
POST /webhooks/facebook/webhook
200 OK  17.16ms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9i03.png

7) We also understand that our RASA APIs are receiving requests from temporary URL and logs are below :

2019-02-20 13:49:39.872185: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
10.0.0.215 - - [2019-02-20 13:53:21] "GET /webhooks/facebook/webhook?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=2057360879&hub.verify_token=C2bot HTTP/1.1" 200 126 0.001643
10.0.0.215 - - [2019-02-20 13:54:46] "POST /webhooks/facebook/webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 122 0.247277
10.0.0.215 - - [2019-02-20 13:55:13] "POST /webhooks/facebook/webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 122 0.141358
10.0.0.215 - - [2019-02-20 13:55:48] "POST /webhooks/facebook/webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 122 0.131841

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LQMc.png

Note :
Some very basic steps that looked in & followed – 
1) Logging out of the profile and again logging in.
2) Unsubscribing the page and again subscribing the page.
3) In roles i can see my name as administrator .

And the same set up was working fine a week before and we were getting response from chatbot but that account got blocked and we created a new account now facing this issue.
Thanks for helping

Comment: My apologies , it seems issue with our model . That i verified by logs of ngrok and rasa .In logs I can only see success response for request that i am getting from bot , but no response message  from our model for the received request.